# Adding Elasticsearch aggregation keys

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to aggregate the CPU values of the PODs in the group.
However, if the aggregation API is based on the POD, which POD is shown in the Key, but it is not known which group the POD belongs to.

Is there a way to include a group in the tally?
I want to know which POD belongs to which group.

ex) In the example below, the group information is unknown.

```
"buckets": [
{
    "key": "myPod",
    "doc_count": 1,
    "1" : {
        "value" : 5
    }
}]
```

sample data:

```
{group=myGroup1, pod=myPod1, value=4},
{group=myGroup1, pod=myPod2, value=5},
{group=myGroup2, pod=myPod3, value=6}
```

Comment: Can you please add sample document as well ?

Comment: @SagarPatel I added the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If the same pod (pod1) is always a part of the same group (group1), you can do something like this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "pod": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pod",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": "group"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if not, you need to to a sub aggregation on the groups

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "pod": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pod",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "group",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```